# Proving the differentiablity of a function.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Consider the differentiablity of the following function:

$$f(x)=x\left(x+3\right)e^{-\frac{x}{2}}$$

My text proves the differentiability by taking **'Left Hand Derivative'** and **'Right Hand Derivative'** and proving them equal.

But can't we do it by taking the differentiation (i.e)

$$\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\left(-x^2+x+6\right)}{2}=\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{2}}}{2}\left(3-x\right)\left(x+2\right)$$

And proving the above to be continuous throughout the given domain?

Comment: Why not applying the handsome rule here that a product of two (or more) differentiable functions is differentiable?

Comment: You cannot prove the function to be differentiable by simply saying "look here, compute the derivative!" To do so would be begging the question. That's like trying to invent gunpowder by buying a tin of gunpowder.

Comment: Looking at lefthand  and righthand derivatives in such an example is **sick**.

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to your question is no. The proof of continuity of $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$ at point $c$, does **not** imply that $f(x)$ is differentiable at point $c$. Further more, you must first prove that $f(x)$ is differentiable before worrying about the continuity of $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$. Continuity does **not** imply differentiability.

You may be confused with the fact that if $f(x)$ is differentiable at point $c$, then $f(x)$ is in fact continuous at point $c$. This does not always work in reverse.

Here is how you can show that $f(x)$ is differentiable

The function $a:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $a(x)=x(x+3)=x^2+3x$ is differentiable at every $c\in\mathbb{R}$ with the derivative $\frac{d}{dx}a(x)=2x+3$, since
$$
\frac{d}{dx}a(c)=\lim_{h\to 0} \left[\frac{(c+h)^2+3(c+h)-c^2-3c}{h}\right]=\lim_{h\to 0} \left[\frac{c^2+2ch+h^2+3c+3h-c^2-3c}{h}\right]
$$
$$
=\lim_{h\to 0} \left[\frac{2ch+h^2+3h}{h}\right]=\lim_{h\to 0} \left[2c+h+3\right]= 2c+3
$$
The function $b:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $b(x)=e^{-\frac{x}{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^x}}$ is differentiable at every $c\in\mathbb{R}$ with the derivative $\frac{d}{dx}b(x)=-\frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{e^x}}$, since
$$
\frac{d}{dx}b(c)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{c+h}}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^c}}}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} \left[\frac{1}{h\sqrt{e^c}\sqrt{e^h}}-\frac{1}{h\sqrt{e^c}}\right]
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^c}}\lim_{h\to 0} \left[\frac{1}{h\sqrt{e^h}}-\frac{1}{h}\right]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^c}}\lim_{h\to 0} \left[\frac{1-\sqrt{e^h}}{h\sqrt{e^h}}\right]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^c}}\lim_{h\to 0} \left[\frac{\frac{d}{dh}\left[1-\sqrt{e^h}\right]}{\frac{d}{dh}\left[h\sqrt{e^h}\right]}\right]
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^c}}\lim_{h\to 0} \left[\frac{-\frac{\sqrt{e^h}}{2}}{(h+2)\frac{\sqrt{e^h}}{2}}\right]=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^c}}\lim_{h\to 0} \left[\frac{1}{h+2}\right]=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{e^c}}
$$
Since $f(x)=a(x)\cdot b(x)=(x^2+3x)e^{-\frac{x}{2}}$ and both $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are differentiable at every $c\in\mathbb{R}$, then $f(x)$ is also differentiable at every $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: k170- I am aware of the above method. I don't why everyone fails to answer to the point. Please shed the example I used above. For any arbitrary function, my question is, can we prove the differentiability by taking its derivative and proving it(the derivative) to be continuous?

Comment: By taking the derivative of something, you already know the function is differentiable everywhere. Before you even think about a rule for differentiating a function, you need to know it's differentiable.

Comment: @HijazAslam, No. You cannot prove the differentiability of a function by taking its derivative and proving that the derivative is continuous. Taking the derivative and showing differentiability are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

it is the product of three differentiable functions, namely $x,x+3,e^{-x/2}$.

Comment: It's a product, not a composition.

Comment: Why are you posting 4 answers?

Comment: Pick out one of your answers for elaboration and delete the others.